# A list of functions? What good is it for?

Tags: r

In this piece of code, it uses list as what appears to be a function to capture functions created upstream of it. Not entirely sure what good is it for nor how each of the pieces fit together. Can someone clarify what this is doing.

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  j <- NULL
  set <- function(y){
  x <<- y
  j <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function()x
  setInverse <- function(inverse) j <<- inverse
  getInverse <- function() j 

  list(set = set, get = get,        #list of functions
  setInverse = setInverse, 
  getInverse = getInverse)
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Memoization and function factories. There is a chapter in Hadley Wickham's book.

Comment: Does that help https://github.com/gustavdelius/datasciencecoursera/blob/master/cachematrix.R?